# Undefined Method : Activate Bin Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I did some editing with my bash profile a few days ago and went to go create a new rails app, and this error pops up. I'm not quite sure what the problem is or why things aren't routed correctly, I thought I had fixed it. I also included my new bash profile, and my old one. I deleted the old one because it looks like it was repeating itself like crazy.

I run

```
$ rails new newapp

/usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>': undefined method `activate_bin_path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Which Gem

```
$ which gem
/Users/LMagnotti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/gem
```

Which Rails

```
 which rails
/usr/local/bin/rails
```

Gem Env

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.4 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 230) [x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/LMagnotti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/LMagnotti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/LMagnotti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/LMagnotti/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/LMagnotti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/LMagnotti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4
     - /Users/LMagnotti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/LMagnotti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin
     - /Users/LMagnotti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/bin
     - /Users/LMagnotti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - ~/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/LMagnotti/.rvm/bin
     - above/path/to/gems
```

New Bash Profile

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
PATH=$PATH:above/path/to/gems

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Old Bash Profile

```
export PATH=/Users/LMagnotti/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/LMagnotti/.rvm/bin:/Lmagnotti/mongodb/bin:/Users/lmagnotti/mongodb/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

The `~` in your PATH assignment does not expand.  You can use `${HOME}` instead of `~` in this situation.

What is up with the relative `above/path/to/gems` in your `PATH` variable?  Are you sure you want to do that?

I suspect one of those is causing the problem, or one of the paths you removed from the original PATH expression is actually needed.